# detect and follow a face by opencv

Tags: opencv

I am working on a project which

1. Detects the face of each person entering the room
2. Saves the face image with exact date and time

I detect the face by using opencv haar cascade "haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml" but I have    2 problems in this project:

1. The speed of face detection is not very high
2. How to avoid saving the same faces in a video (I want to save just 1 face for each person )

Answer (score 0):

1. try one of the lbp-cascades, trade in speed for accuracy
2. it seems , you have not thought about this properly. to distinguish one face from the other, you would need actual face-recognition (which , again, would require you to collect a couple of imaged from each person for training).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `optic flow` to track a face once it has been detected, and then avoid detecting a new face in that region, it's only an approximation, but it can get you some pretty good results.